# libgit2 how to get the the status of the current directory?

Tags: git, libgit2

How can I get the status of a single directory, rather than the whole repository?

I have looked at the following:

- `git_status_list_new` which gets the repository status, but I care only about files located in a single directory.
- `git_status_file` which gets the status of a single.

Is there a way that I can get the status of a single directory using libgit2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git_status_list_new` accepts a `git_status_options` struct, which contains a `pathspec` member which controls which files will be included in the list. You can use that to limit your returned statuses to those in a single directory.